# facing difficulties in the alignment of text in html

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

```css
.box{
        margin: 0 auto; 
        width:400px //you can set it in %.
        height: 600px;
        padding:20px;
        background:#f9f9f9;
        border:4px solid #333;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Forms</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <center>
        <div class="box">
          <img src="1.png" align="right">
          <h1>Form Updation</h1>

          <form name="first" method="get" action="https://www.mi.com/in/">

            First name : <input type="text" name="fname" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>
            Last name : <input type="text" name="Lname" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>
            Password : <input type="password" name="Password" size="10" maxlength="15"><br><br>
            Nationalaity : <input type="text" name="Country" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>

            Phone Number : <input type="text" name="Phone" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>


          </form>

        </div>
      </center>

  </body>
</html>
```

output -
[Phone number is not in proper arrangemnt with the above one i need to come with phone number in arrangement like all in centre and onething is that i want these 5 should come up with by another eans there is some space which is left out in other work all the fillup section must come with space index.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to get what you want but i guess your question is how can I align texts and inputs in a nice order.

So we can think a way to do that in your code.

Firstly think your text and input parts as an one. We can take the text in a div and give that a width like 50% or 33%. After that we can define another div for input and give it the remaining width or directly give the remaining width to input.

Up to now

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#form{
  width:50%
}
#form div,
#form input{
  display:inline-block;
}
#form div{
  width:35%;
}
#form input{
  width:65%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="first" method="get" action="https://www.mi.com/in/">

        <div>First name : </div><input type="text" name="fname" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>
        <div>Last name : </div><input type="text" name="Lname" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>
        <div>Password : </div><input type="password" name="Password" size="10" maxlength="15"><br><br>
        <div>Nationalaity : </div><input type="text" name="Country" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>
        <div>Phone Number : </div><input type="text" name="Phone" size="15" maxlength="25"><br><br>

</form>
```

But don't forget to make your components box-sizing to border-box. If you don't when you give to 33% and 66% width or anything that sums 100% won't work as side by side. Your input will get new line.So we give our form a width that we want, after that we made our input and div inline-block to get side by side nad then give the widths. If you want to center your text you can add text-align:left to your divs.

```
#form div{
  width:35%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

#form represent our form with it's id that we gave, #form div represent the divs that inside that form( you can check combinators) and so on. Here is a link for combinators either.

[Combinators in CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)